# Why doesn't Fermat's Little theorem work for 4 and 9?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

4 and 9 are relatively prime, but $4^8$ = 65536, which is not $1 \mod 9$. I can't figure out why because I've been told that $a^{p-1}$ is equivalent to $1 \mod p$ if $p$ and $a$ are relatively prime...so...what am I missing?

Comment: Yes, I know, Fermat

Comment: $\varphi(9)$ is not $8$ but is $6.$

Comment: You do need $\gcd(a, p) = 1$ but you *also* need for $p$ to be either prime OR a pseudoprime to base $a$. As it happens, 4 *is* a pseudoprime to base 9: verify that $9^3 \equiv 1 \mod 4$.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can't apply Fermat's theorem: $$a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod p$$

because $9$ is not a prime.
However,you can use Euler's theorem:

$$a^{\phi(m)} \equiv 1 \pmod m$$

$$a=4$$

$$m=9$$

$$(a,m)=1$$

$$\phi(9)=\phi(3^2)=3^2 \left (1-\frac{1}{3} \right )=9 \frac{2}{3}=6$$

Therefore:

$$4^6 \equiv 1 \pmod 9$$

Comment: Ok then, I guess the textbook is wrong, it says it applies if p is prime or a and p are coprime

Comment: @Nethesis That should be *and* a and $p$ are coprime. Must be a typo

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand the difference between a and $a$...

Comment: There is no difference

Comment: @Nethesis You can only apply the Ferma'ts theorem if $p$ is a prime AND $(a,p)=1$.

Comment: Ohh, thank you, the book did not phrase it in that way at all, thank you

Comment: There is a difference but humans are able to resolve it most of the time, it just slows things down when you have to stop and think as to which is meant. "a" is grammatical particle of the English language, "$a$" is a mathematical symbol that can stand for a variable.

Answer (score 7):

Fermat's Little Theorem is true only if $p$ is **prime** - the statement is  $$a^p \equiv a \mod p$$ for $p$ prime. When $(a,p) = 1$, this is equivalent to the usual formulation of the theorem (we can divide by $a$): $$a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \mod p$$ if $p$ is prime and $(a,p) = 1$.  In this case, $9$ is not prime, so the theorem will fail.

---

There is however a generalisation that works for all integers, usually called the **Fermat-Euler Theorem**: we define $\phi(n)$ to be the number of integers less than $n$ that are coprime to $n$. Then if $(a,n)=1$, $$a^{\phi(n)}  \equiv 1 \mod n$$

We have $\phi(9) = 6$ and indeed, $4^6 \equiv 1 \mod 9$.

Comment: And $9$ is not prime, which is why the theorem fails in this case.

Comment: Fermat's Theorem holds in any finite field-even ones of non-prime order. So in any finite field of order $q$, we have $a^q=a$. This does not mean that $a^q\equiv a\mod q$ for each prime power $q$. This is because multiplication in $\Bbb F_q$ is different from multiplication in $\Bbb Z/q\Bbb Z$.

Comment: I've never heard that general theorem called Fermat's theorem - I had always thought of Fermat as specifically referring to $\mathbb Z / p\mathbb Z$. Although both follow simply from Lagrange's theorem for finite groups